# How to set "ResourceDictionary" as the content of the "Window" in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls, resourcedictionary

I am trying to set a ResourceDictionary as the content of window in WPF. technically we can initialize a window with the corresponding view model. but when it comes to the output then the view is coming with the namespace of the view model, not with associated ResourceDictionary for the relevant view model. here is the tried example and output window. Please help me to resolve this problem.

```
public void ShowDialog(IDocumentPublishDialogViewModel dialogViewModel)
    {
        if (dialogViewModel is ContinuousJournalPrintViewModel)
        {
            Window continuousJournalPrintWindow = new ContinuousJournalPrintWindow
            {
                Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow,
                Title = "New Continuous Journal Print",
                Content = dialogViewModel
            };

            continuousJournalPrintWindow.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            PrepareCloseAction(dialogViewModel);

            if (dialogViewModel is ChooseDraftOrTasksViewModel)
            {
                GuiDispatcherField.Invoke(() => DialogServiceField.ShowPopupDialog(dialogViewModel, dialogViewModel.CloseAction, () => true, true));
            }
            else
            {
                GuiDispatcherField.Invoke(() => DialogServiceField.ShowPopupDialog(dialogViewModel, dialogViewModel.CloseAction, () => true, true, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch, VerticalAlignment.Stretch));
            }
        }
    }

<ResourceDictionary x:Class="DIPSASD.DynamicPublish.Client.Views.Previews.ContinuousJournalPrintView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:dc="http://DIPSASD.no/Arenade/UI"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DIPSASD.DynamicPublish.Client.ViewModels.Previews"
         mc:Ignorable="d">


<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ContinuousJournalPrintViewModel}">        

    <dc:TextBlock Text="Team Y-KNOTS"></dc:TextBlock>

</DataTemplate>
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image: output window]

Comment: You might be asking how the DataTemplate in the ResourceDictionary would be automatically applied when you set the Content of a ContentControl to a ContinuousJournalPrintViewModel instance. Move the DataTemplate to Application.Resources in App.xaml.

Comment: I guess you may not have merged that resource dictionary or used it in the window resources. But you're not setting the resource dictionary as content.  With what you have there it's not at all clear why you wouldn't just have a textblock as the window content or why you don't just merge your resource dictionary in app.xaml as Clemens suggests.  Maybe you should explain what your purpose is. In  the question.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for your comment. What I want is to know how we can set some content to the window from the view model side. Initially, I was trying using a resource dictionary but came these issues, then I tried user control. It also didn't work. do you have any idea how we can set the content to the window?

Comment: Instead of `Content = dialogViewModel` try `DataContext = dialogViewModel` and put `<ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>` into the Window's XAML. Make sure the DataTemplate is declared in `Window.Resources` - or in `Application.Resources` in App.xaml.